# How to loop through text files (containing path to some files lets say a,b,c) and copy the files inside the text file

Tags: linux, bash, tcl

Please help me with linux command to loop through and copy the files a,b,c. inside a,b,c there are further path of files mentioned (lets say a has 1,2,3| file b has 4,5,6 | file c has 7,8,9). i need to copy all files, a,b,c,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 in my local directory.

example: content of file a is shown:

```
/path/to/file/1 
/path/to/file/2
/path/to/file/3
```

content of file b is shown:

```
/path/to/file/4
/path/to/file/5
/path/to/file/6
```

content of file c is shown:

```
/path/to/file/7 and so on.
```

i need to copy all the files which has their path mentioned

Comment: `while IFS= read -r files; do [[ -f "$files" ]] && cp -v "$files" /path/to/destination/; done < <(cat a b c)`

Comment: Look into `cp(1)`, esp. its `-p` option. Also of interest may be `basename(1)` and `dirname(1)`. Do `man cp`, `man basename` and `man dirname`.

Comment: I'm curious why you used the [tag:tcl] tag. In what format do you have the initial list of files a, b, c?

Answer (score 1):

Using `tcl`:

```
set destdir [pwd]
foreach filename {a b c} {
    set f [open $filename r]
    set files [split [read $f] \n]
    close $f
    file copy -- {*}$files $destdir
}
```

Or `bash`:

```sh
for filename in a b c; do
    readarray -t files <"$filename"
    cp -- "${files[@]}" .
done
```